# google-app-engine firebase-admin python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, google-app-engine-python, firebase-admin

I'm attempting to setup firebase-admin with google-app-engine standard python. My dev environment is windows and I've followed the library setup as indicated in how to install 3rd party libraries. The firebase website indicates that firebase-admin has been tested on app engine, but there are no instructions or indication as to whether it was tested in standard, flexible or both. I've started with the most basic example and just tried the first import from the firebase generic documentation.

```
import webapp2
import firebase_admin

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

The result is

> ImportError: The requests library is not installed, please install the
>   requests package to use the requests transport.

The requests library in lib during the install of firebase-admin so I'm not sure why I get this message. If I add import requests immediately before import firebase_admin I will instead get this message.

> ImportError: No module named _winreg

I'd like to use firebase-admin if at all possible so if anyone is familiar with this situation and how to resolve it please let me know. Also, I am not interested in using the flexible environment, this is a question for the standard environment only.

Comment: firebase-admin has been tested in standard GAE. Are you vendoring the dependencies correctly into your project? Depending on your use case, you may also have to follow the additional steps documented at http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#the-app-engine-standard-environment. The problem with the _winreg library seems to be Windows specific issue in the App Engine dev server.

Comment: @YannickMG the link is not accessible. It looks like you must be a google employee to get in. I look forward to upcoming fix.

Comment: Sorry about the mixup! Corrected message: About the _winger error a fix for the issue should be available in an upcoming release. A potential workaround was suggested [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900351#comment13).

Answer (score 3):

-Install necessary modules under lib;
    pip install -t lib/ firebase-admin
    pip install -t lib/ requests-toolbelt

-you can delete the .pyc files as they are just the precompiled versions of the .py files that are also there (and will be regenerated when .py is executed).

-add below code in added the appengine_config.py;

from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')

import requests
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

import platform

def patch(module):
    def decorate(func):
        setattr(module, func.func_name, func)
        return func
    return decorate

@patch(platform)
def platform():
    return 'AppEngine'

- see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/FzEG2U6SRN8